# Translating the custom text in form.phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, contact-us

I have added some paragraph to form.phtml file and added the translation in the `.../locale/nl_NL/Mage_Contacts.csv`. But the custom text does not get translated in contact us page when I switch the languages. I have refresh the cache of magento and browser. What step is missing?

Comment: @7ochem , the answer of the fschmengler was the solution to my issue, so I closed the topic. May I know why you removed my closed tag from title?

Comment: Hi Zinat, welcome to Magento SE. The SE websites are a Q&A and are not only here for people to ask questions, but (maybe mainly) also a great resource for others. Therefor we don't "close" a question once it is answered. There's lots of indicators that show you if a question has (accepted) answers and/or votes, for instance see the questions page: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not show, how you added the paragraph, but this is what it *should* look like so that it gets translated by `Mage_Contacts.csv`:

```
Mage::helper('contacts')->__('here is your paragraph');
```